Create Standalone script that can be run in multiple spreadsheets
I am still very much a beginner, but I have worked hard to learn how to script, albeit at a very basic level. I'm in the unfortunate position where I have become aware that people are trying to copy my work to use for there own purposes. The desire to do this is because of the functionality of the scripts.
I'm aware that I can create Standalone scripts which can reference the small number of spreadsheets that run the same script, but I am concerned that it will take me too long to work out how to do this, before copies have been made (unfortunately, we're part way through an event and I cannot remove access).
I would be grateful if someone could explain to me how I can go about creating a standalone script for the below, and how to create an array of spreadsheet IDs for the script to run on.
Your help would be greatly appreciated.
function onEdit(e) 
{ UpdateLog(e);
  FurtherUpdateLog(e);
  VehicleLog(e);
  Dropdown(e);
}

function UpdateLog(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const shts = ['CV Event Control Log'];
  const idx = shts.indexOf(sh.getName());
  if(~idx )
            {
              if(e.range.columnStart !== 3) return;
              var o = e.range.offset(0, -1)
              if(!o.getValue()) o.setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss"))};
};

function FurtherUpdateLog(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const shts = ['CV Event Control Log'];
  const idx = shts.indexOf(sh.getName());
  if(~idx )
            {
              if(e.range.columnStart !== 6) return;
              var o = e.range.offset(0, -1)
              if(!o.getValue()) o.setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss"))};
};

function VehicleLog(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const shts = ['Vehicle Tow Log'];
  const idx = shts.indexOf(sh.getName());
  if(~idx )
            {
              if(e.range.columnStart !== 3) return;
              var o = e.range.offset(0, -1)
              if(!o.getValue()) o.setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss"))};
};


function Dropdown(e) {
  var oldValue;
  var newValue;
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
  
  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 9 && activeCell.getLastRow && ss.getActiveSheet().getName()=="CV Event Control Log") {
  newValue=e.value;
  oldValue=e.oldValue;
  if(!e.value) {
                activeCell.setValue("");
  }
else {
      if (!e.oldValue) {
      activeCell.setValue(newValue);
    }
else {
      activeCell.setValue(oldValue+', '+newValue);
    }
}
}
}


A standalone script for an onEdit() trigger? Where's the trigger going to come from? The project has to contain the script and the trigger and be contained by the spreadsheet.  That's what I think anyway.

You might use the feature to test add-ons or deploy your standalone script as an add-on.
For details on testing, see the official documentation: Test an Editor Add-on

Simple triggers might be used on contained / bound Google Apps Script projects and Editor's add-ons.
If the script is used by a small group of users, such as a small work team, you might avoid publishing an add-on. Still, you need to understand the basics of developing an Editor add-on, which is not very different from writing a script bound to Google Editor's file, in this case, a spreadsheet. However, using a standalone script makes things a bit harder as a few additional steps are required:

Create a test deployment
Run a test deployment

Note: Test deployment doesn't support installable triggers, but they support simple triggers.

Thank you for directing me to the right area in the documentation. I would like to better understand how to write scripts, but with the time sensitivity of the request, I would hoping someone would be able to offer me specific guidance on how to adapt my script to be a standalone script, whilst still also working onEdit.
Thank you for taking the time to reply.

@JonHarris Your question is leaning toward requiring a lot of back and forth / requiring more focus. You should try to make a more specific question. P.D. I'm online on Codementor https://codementor.io/@rbn now.

@JonHarris, I have updated my answer. However, if something is unclear about creating and running a test deployment or if you encounter a problem, please feel free to ask a follow-up question. Be specific and don't hesitate to ask multiple questions if needed.

Thank you for your time. I'm making progress... I can get the script working when there is only x1 function, I just need to figure out how to get the installed onEdit trigger to work across all x3 functions.
